# Server-sent events - still worth checking out?

Tags: websocket, server-sent-events

As WebSockets seem to get a lot more attention, and are capable of doing everything Server-sent Events can (and more), are SSE still worth checking out?

It seems that SSE are easier to use but considering the amount of articles and libraries it seems WebSockets are the clear winner here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need something quick and dirty, without all the bells and whistles of WebSockets, and something that's stable and supported, as well as doesn't have any known security issues, then SSE are just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Also, flash is required to support bidirectional communication for websockets in browsers without native websockets (ie8-ie9).
For SSE there are pure js polyfills, that implements xhr(xdr)-streaming for all browser(ie8+)